# Updating a suggested edit

Tags: support

Sometimes I suggest an edit for a thread and realize I've missed something out. Of course, I edit the post again and submit it, however does this update your previous suggested edit on the thread, or does it create a new suggested edit?

If it doesn't update your suggested edit, is there a way to "cancel" your suggested edit and then submit a new suggested edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the previous edit has not been approved, yes, the new edit will update your existing suggested edit. It's much like editing in the grace period, in that the changes are made into one revision. If your edit hasn't yet been approved, there's no reason to create a *second* suggestion for the same post that's basically the same edit with another tweak or two.

There is no way to cancel or take back a suggested edit.

Comment: That makes sense... thanks Kendra, I just wanted some clarification :)

Comment: "no way to cancel" ... I just stumbled on this and tried to edit it back to the original to effectively cancel, but then got told I had to change at least 6 characters.